# Unable to post to json data

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error while trying to post image together with json data.
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "price")enter image description here

```
   let imageUrl;

   const BusBoy = require('busboy');
   const path = require('path');
   const os = require('os');
   const fs = require('fs');

   const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });

   let imageToBeUploaded = {};
   let imageFileName;

   busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
     console.log(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype);
     if (mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && mimetype !== 'image/png') {
       return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Wrong file type submitted' });
     }
     // my.image.png => ['my', 'image', 'png']
     const imageExtension = filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
     // 32756238461724837.png
     imageFileName = `${Math.round(
       Math.random() * 1000000000000
     ).toString()}.${imageExtension}`;
     const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
     imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
     file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
   });
   busboy.on('finish', () => {
     admin
       .storage()
       .bucket(`${config.storageBucket}`)
       .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
         resumable: false,
         metadata: {
           metadata: {
             contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
           }
         }
       })
       .then(() => {
         imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${
           config.storageBucket
         }/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
         const newProduct = {
             description: req.body.description,
             price: req.body.price,
             title: req.body.title,
             createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
             likeCount:0,
             reviewCount:0,
             orderCount: 0,
             storeName: req.user.userName,
             sellerImage: req.user.imageUrl,
             imageUrl: imageUrl,
         };

         db .collection('products')
             .add(newProduct)
             .then(doc => {
                 const resProduct = newProduct;
                 resProduct.productId = doc.id;
                 res.json(resProduct);
             })

       })
       .then(() => {
         return res.json({ message: 'product uploaded successfully' });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.error(err);
         return res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong' });
       });
   });
   busboy.end(req.rawBody);
};
```

Is it possible to post file and json data together in postman?

Comment: The error I'm getting is this: Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "price")

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you have a field called "price" which has the value undefined. Undefined is not a valid Firestore value. You will have to figure out why that is and what it's supposed to be.  Check the value of `req.body.price`.  If you can't give it a proper value, remove it from the object.

Comment: Thanks for the help.When I remove this ```description: req.body.description,price: req.body.price,title: req.body.title,``` form the object  it works. But is there a way to add those values to the object.

Comment: Sure, as I said, the value is undefined.  You will need to make sure that the value is valid for Firestore.  We don't know where the value comes from, so you will have to determine that.